# Checking page before applying image restrictions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

so users can upload images on my website and I want to put some restrictions on these images. The catch is that these image restriction can only apply on one page, being the edit product page. I already tried checking by template and ID of the page but this page lives below a parent page so that did not work.
I currently have the code below but now it is rejecting all images and not displaying the correct message. Anyone that can help me out?

```
function resize_image_resolution($file) {
if (is_user_wcmp_vendor(get_current_user_id()) && isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) && false !== strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'edit-product' ) ) {
    $image = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
    $minimum = array(
        'width' => '1080', //set your minimum
        'height' => '1080'
    );
    $maximum = array(
        'width' => '12000', //set your maximum
        'height' => '12000'
    );
    $image_width = $image[0];
    $image_height = $image[1];

    $too_small = "Image dimensions are too small.";
    $too_large = "Image dimensions are too large.";

    if ( $image_width < $minimum['width'] || $image_height < $minimum['height'] ) {
        $file['error'] = $too_small;
        return $file;
    } elseif ( $image_width > $maximum['width'] || $image_height > $maximum['height'] ) {
        $file['error'] = $too_large;
        return $file;
    } else {
        return $file;
    }
}
```

}
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'resize_image_resolution');

Comment: Can you expand on "did not work" and "not displaying the correct message" please? And perhaps show the values you get in `$image`.

Comment: You probably need an `else return $file;` for the main `if`.

Comment: @droopsnoot "Did not work" meaning that the image restrictions were working on all pages, instead of only the edit product page. All these vendor user pages live under the same parent page. "Not displaying the correct message" meaning that it always shows a message saying "specified file failed upload test." for all files that are uploaded, even if dimensions are correct.

Comment: @KenY-N I think that I already have an `else return $file;` for main `if` at the end of the function?

Comment: I mean the `if` on the second line `if (is_user_wcmp_vendor(...`. It's not going to fix your bug, I don't think, but it might affect other places where you upload files.

Comment: PS: [wordpress.se] might be better able to help you?

Comment: @KenY-N Yes I need to apply this to check if user is a vendor, otherwise the function should not be applied. You are correct, I will reach out on WordPress Development as this issue is more specifically relate to WordPress :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for helping me. Eventually I have been able to get it working with following code:

```
    /*Check image resolution*/
/** Upload image restriction ****/
function resize_image_resolution($file) {
    $current_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    if(is_user_wcmp_vendor(get_current_user_id()) && strpos($current_url, 'dashboard/edit-product') !== false){
        $image = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
            $minimum = array(
                'width' => '1080',   //set your minimum
                'height' => '1080'
            );
            $maximum = array(
                'width' => '12000',  //set your maximum
                'height' => '12000'
            );
            $image_width = $image[0];
            $image_height = $image[1];

            $too_small = "The minimum size of your design has to be 1080 pixels";
            $too_large = "The maximum size of your design has to be 12000 pixels";

            if ( $image_width < $minimum['width'] || $image_height < $minimum['height'] ) {
                $file['error'] = $too_small; 
                return $file;
            }
            elseif ( $image_width > $maximum['width'] || $image_height > $maximum['height'] ) {
                $file['error'] = $too_large; 
                return $file;
            }
            else
                return $file;
    } else {
            return $file;
    }
}
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'resize_image_resolution');
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you.  It would appear there are a few typos, and you should return $file at the end.

```
function resize_image_resolution( $file ) {
    if ( is_user_wcmp_vendor( get_current_user_id() ) && isset( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) && false !== strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'edit-product' ) ) {
        $image        = getimagesize( $file['tmp_name'] );
        $minimum      = array(
            'width'  => '1080', // set your minimum.
            'height' => '1080',
        );
        $maximum      = array(
            'width'  => '12000', // set your maximum.
            'height' => '12000',
        );
        $image_width  = $image[0];
        $image_height = $image[1];

        if ( $image_width <= $minimum['width'] || $image_height >= $minimum['height'] ) {
            $file['error'] = 'Image dimensions are too small.';
        } elseif ( $image_width > $maximum['width'] || $image_height > $maximum['height'] ) {
            $file['error'] = 'Image dimensions are too large.';
        }
    }
    return $file;
}
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'resize_image_resolution' );
```

Comment: Thanks for thinking with me. Just tried and unfortunately this is not working. When implementing this function it lets me upload any image and is not displaying any messages

Comment: Just to clarify, the function was working when simply using `if(is_user_wcmp_vendor(get_current_user_id())){`. Problem is that it should only be applied on edit product page. This is the path of the page: /dashboard/edit-product/**Product ID**/

Comment: The issue would be that you can't get that it's edit product from the upload prefilter since the request_uri is ` "/wp-admin/async-upload.php"`  and the global $pagenow is `async-upload.php` - because that is the upload screen.

Comment: I see, this could be quite annoying indeed. Any workarounds for this issue? Unfortunately I still haven't been able to find a solution. Someone suggested my to try to do the checking with WP hooks but not sure how to try this as I'm still very new to PHP and WP